# Create and write to files based on list with like items

Tags: python

I have a CSV file with 237 lines of transactions, I've already figured out to group, sort, and create a new CSV file with the transactions in the correct order sorted by account number.  However I'd like to go one step further and create multiple CSV files based on the account number with all of that account number's transactions.

I think what I'd like to do just append each line to the appropiate CSV file based on the account number, but I'd like to do this dynamically so I don't have to create each variable since there is always an unknown number of account numbers.

```
Account #, Date, Dollar Amount (stored as heading)
001, 1/1/11, $25
001, 1/1/11, $20
002, 1/1/11, $15
003, 1/4/11, $19
```

So with this data I'd like to create three separate CSV files based on the Account number.  I am not looking for someone to write the code, but I am hoping there is some module in Python I'm unaware of that involves this type of process.  If someone could please point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: On tasks like this, it is always preferrable (I think) to gather all the data first, and only then write the results to file. Opening files in append mode is good if the file is intended to grow, like log or history files. In your case, you should gather all the data from your main CSV, group it in the appropriate way, and then write each file at once, one after another. It is much slower to talk about than to actually run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick (and probably not so efficient) solution.

```
from sets import Set
import csv

source = list(csv.reader(open("account_file.csv")))

accounts = Set(line[0] for line in source)

for account in accounts:
    out = open(account+".csv","w")
    out.write( "\n".join(",".join(x) for x in source if x[0] == account))
    out.close()
```

Comment: Well thank you very much, this did exactly what I needed.  Not sure which answer to make as the solution since one was teaching me to fish and one gave me the fish.  I understand the solution and why it works, but I need to read a bit more on lists and sets to fully comprehend.

Comment: @akevit In this solution, the file is read as many times as there are different accounts. That's not very good. Take care of the fact also that the mode 'w' will make any previously existing file to disappear

Comment: @eyquem That's OK regarding the previously existing files disappearing, and I changed the source variable to an existing variable I have that contains the entire contents of the CSV (sorted) as a list of lists.  Not sure if that changes the efficiency of the program.

Comment: @akevit In the above code, the content of the file is kept as value of object **source**, then for each element in **accounts** there is execution of a loop ``for x in source``: the content of the file is examined several times, even if it is not read several time as I erroneously wrote it. If you put this content in another object, it does nothing radically different, even if the data are sorted in this other object. It's a pity to read several times something when it's possible not to do so , see my code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such module. I would create separate lists for each account operations and put them on the dictionary where key is account number. Then after iterating whole input file you can save each list to separate `.csv` file.

If your input file is already sorted then you can simply copy line to output file, then when account changes close output file and open next output file for new account.

Comment: That goes along my previous comment on saving the output files one by one, and not in append mode.

Comment: Thanks both of you, for some reason that idea didn't come to me.  I was going to try to implement this with dictionaries in some way but then I'd have to sort each file after the fact.  This way should work and I think I can figure it out -- Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need of CSV interface, I prefer this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from os.path import getsize

with open('accounts.csv') as f:

    first_line = f.readline()

    d = defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        d[line.split(',')[0]].append(line)

    for account,lines in d.iteritems():
        with open(account+'.csv','a') as f:
            if getsize(account+'.csv')==0:
                f.write(first_line)
            f.write(''.join(lines))
```

The file is read only one time

Comment: I trust this will work but unfortunately what I have works and it will more than satisfy my needs.  I don't see the number of transactions to increase by any huge amount my code now only takes a couple of seconds.  I will definitely take a better look at what you wrote when I have some free time to learn some new things.  --Thank you.